# How to get from Istanbul Atatürk Airport to Çanakkale‎?

Tags: public-transport, turkey, istanbul, isl

The usual way to get from Istanbul to Çanakkale‎ is to take a direct bus from the Büyük or the Harem otogar (bus station). That's especially true if you stay somewhere in the "center" of Istanbul. But what if you arrive by plane at Atatürk airport somewhere between 5 PM and 2 AM (exact arrival time not yet known)?

I imagine that one solution would be to take a taxi, shuttle or even public transport to one of the above mentioned bus stations and to proceed from there. But now I wonder if there is no other option from the airport? Aren't there direct buses to Çanakkale‎ leaving from the airport, or nearby? In case of a late arrival you would save some precious time by not having to go to one of the bus stations first.

I am looking for a "public-transport" solution. Taxi rides to bridge shorter distances are okay, but not a private taxi ride for the whole distance.

Comment: Is Car rental an option?  I found roads in Turkey to be excellent and easy to navigate.  Likewise, I found gas to be reasonable compared to most of Europe and car rental itself cheap on the internet.  I agree about taking a ferry across the Bosprous, but are you okay driving?

Comment: Not really. I would prefer not to drive myself. This being said, I find neither rental cars nor the fuel really cheap in Turkey ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take the metro from Ataturk Airport to Esenler "Otogar"   (much nearer than Harem).

From the [public transit website](http://www.istanbul-ulasim.com.tr/en), you can see the timetable, Metro runs until Midnight (00.00). From Esenler Otogar you can get a suitable coach for your travel.

Answer (score 7):

As naive as it sounds, here is my shot:

Take a taxi from the airport to the Bakırköy‎ (it's less then 10 km). From there take a [ferry to Yenikapı‎](http://www.ido.com.tr/en/yolculuk-oncesi/tarifeler/341-bostanci-kadikoy-bakirkoy) (first stop, Istanbul direction, it should be pretty fast) and then take a ferry to Bandırma, which would take about 1 hour 45 minutes. 
[Here](http://www.ido.com.tr/en/yolculuk-oncesi/tarifeler/351-yenikapi-bandirma) is the timetable for this last part.

After arriving to Bandırma take a taxi or minibus to the bus terminal and take a bus to Canakkale. It's about 170 km, 2 to 3 hours.

> The Schedule of the 2 most prefered bus companies from Bandırma to Canakkale are as follow;
>
> [Canakkale Truva](http://www.truvaturizm.com/); 11:00 a.m., 14:00, 16:00, 17:45, 18:30, 21:00, 02:00
>   a.m.
>
> [Kamil Koç](http://www.kamilkoc.com.tr/): 11:00 a.m., 12:00, 14:00, 15:00, 18:00, 20:00, 22:00,
>   23:45.

If it's doable or not it's up to you, but IT surely is a different way to make this trip :-)

Comment: Interesting option, though not really what I am looking for. By any chance, do you know where to find the schedules for the Ataköy - Yenikapı‎ ferry?

Comment: if you look in google maps it seems [this](http://www.ido.com.tr/en/yolculuk-oncesi/tarifeler/341-bostanci-kadikoy-bakirkoy) is the line that stop in Atakoy and goes to Yenikapi.

Comment: Indeed. But it seems that the stop (assuming it is one) is not indicated in the IDO schedules.

Comment: look [here](http://www.ido.com.tr/en/interaktif-haritalar/ic-hatlar), apparently the port isn't Atakoy but Bakirkoy, close to the airport

Answer (score 1):

There are often buses to canakkale from istanbul but only the thing is mainly they are fully booked because of the 100th Anniversary of the world war 1.
better you book your bus before you arrive in turkey. There is website they offer good services for bus booking http://www.ticketlineturkey.com and http://www.busticketline.com